# Activerecord two different associations between same models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, many-to-many

I'm just starting in Ruby on Rails

I have a model User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

and a model Post

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, foreign_key: 'user_id', class_name: 'User'
end
```

I want to let users share a post with other users, but i'm trully lost, I have tried a many to many association with a table Sharing and using :through, but I only got more confused, I could really use a hand, thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by 'share with other users'?

Comment: that a post can be seen by those you share it with, like sharing a document in google docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 1st solution

If you don't need more information about shared post (like when it is shared, why , etc...)

In User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # created posts
  has_many :posts,
      :foreign_key => :user_id 
  # shared posts
  has_and_belongs_to_many :shared_posts
end
```

In Post model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :viewers
end
```

Migration

```
create_table :posts_users do |t|
   t.references :user
   t.references :post
end
```

---

2nd Solution

If you do need more information ( when it was shared, does the user can comment, or ...). You should use the `through`

In user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # created posts
  has_many :posts,
      :foreign_key => :user_id 
  # shared posts
  has_many :shares, 
      class_name: "Post"
  has_many :shared_posts,
      through: :shares
end
```

In Post model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author,
       class_name: 'User'
  # shared posts
  has_many :shares
  has_many :viewers,
       through: :shares
end
```

In Share model

```
class Share < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :post
end
```

See also [Choosing between has_many_and_belongs_to has_many through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many)